# HP DL380 G8 - SAS Cage Power

Tags: hp

[HP DL380 G8 8 Bay 2.5" Drive Cage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FgkA.jpg)

I have been given a HP DL380 G8 Drive cage - duplicated order 
I want to use it on a NON HP Server

On the back of the 8bay 2.5" drive cage there is a 8 pin power connector

Does anyone know what the pinout is so I can rig up to normal ATX-12 power supply?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a reasonable business practice. Why would you want to use this drive cage in a non-HP server?

You may be better served using a proper external enclosure or doing something native to the server type you have.

Comment: its NOT a Business Server... Basically a PC.
I built a "PC" using 6 Core AMD CPU to teach myself Windows 2012 Server, Linux etc at Home

Comment: When you sign up to serverfault we put words in front of you, we expect you to read them, one part says this site is for professional systems not home ones.

Comment: opps - can't edit
its NOT a Business Server... Basically a PC.
I built a "PC" using 6 Core AMD CPU to teach myself Windows 2012 Server, Linux etc at Home.
The Hot Swap cage was offered by our IT guy who managed to duplicated order for 3 servers + drive cage - so 3 unused drive cages used sitting in a corner !
Apparently, these things were £30... 
if I try to buy a generic Hot swap cage I won't get one for less than £ 200!!!!
I was also given 4 x 2.5" 300Gb SAS drives because we upgraded to SSD's for speed

Comment: I know I won't get very far with this...
my company paid for my "Home" Server since its help me with testing servers etc. They couldn't justify buying me a DL380 - havingsaid that there is nothing my server can't do that a HP box can !

Comment: @bhrt60 if for labbing, just use a normal HDD, you gain nothing except more big electricy bill to use a full cage disk enclosure for a lab server. To give an example my lab server at home is on a atom cpu with a normal laptop hdd.